# Migrate saved logins

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've been using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 for a while (on Windows 10, if that matters) and I've collected a good bunch of saved logins.

I've now installed version 17.2, which apparently installs side by side (rather than replacing previous version), and my logins are not available in this version.

Is there a way to migrate them from 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All cached logins are saved on `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\%Version%\SqlStudio.bin`

Each time you run SSMS and save a login, it is added to SqlStudio.bin file. Now i assume your new SSMS has no saved logins, therefore simply replace SqlStudio.bin with the one from old SSMS

Steps:

Go to: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin` , copy that file and then go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0` and replace the existing one.